# how remove ng-repeat from DOM using JQuery and update ( splice ) the angular $scope object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im using AngularJS ng-repeat concept to render dynamic widgets. So I have Scope object e.g $scope.items = [{object vlaue}]; By using angular factory items object values will be updated and loads the widgets through ng-repeat. The above is done. Now i want to Remove the widget using Jquery remove mothod and need to splice the items from the scope object. 
If i splice the items scope object, widget is removed from DOM. But if i Removed the widgtes using JQuery Remove mothod, that scope items object not updated. How can i update the items even widget removed from DOM.

Comment: why don't you just remove the item from ng-repeat array? it will get removed from DOM by angular automatically... there is no need to use jquery

Comment: I want to remove particular item only. Don't want to remove all items scope object and also im using query animation throught out my app for removing dom elements. It's hard to do same thing again using Angular animation. Thats why i want to remove to remove the dom using jquery and need to update(i mean splice the items array) for the particular using AngularJS.

Comment: I don't think it's hard, since angular uses a piece of jQuery (jQLite), but more importantly it's definitely not a good idea to mix jQuery DOM removal with directives like ng-repeat. Removing the particular element from the ng-repeat array feed is very simple, you just need to add the animation which you use. There is no need to use angular animation, I think a simple CSS3 animation is enough. You just attach a css class to an element, after animationEnd you remove it from the array and it's done

Comment: Another idea to address your animation issue is to wrap your required jquery in directives